# Flutter - Custom gradient button turns white on Android device

Tags: android, flutter

After developing my application in an emulator and tablet. I decided to try it out on one of the devices that our business is currently using (Casio VR-7000 running Android 4.2.2). I have discovered an issue with my custom gradient buttons [as you can see in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AujZ.jpg)

[This is how it looks like in the emulator running on the same Android version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga8cE.png)

Following is the code related to the button:

```
Container(
    width: width,
    height: height,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: gradient,
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onPressed,
        child: Center(
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

As you can see it's just a container that takes a width and height with a Box Decoration that takes in a gradient. Following is how I use the button:

```
GradientButton(
    onPressed: () => buttonHandler(buttonValue),
    gradient: gradient ??
        const LinearGradient(colors: [
          Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
          Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 27, 27),
        ], begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: Alignment.bottomRight),
    child: Text(
      buttonValue,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: deviceSize.height * 0.03,
      ),
    ))
```

I am not sure why this problem is only occurring on the Casio device and not inside of the emulator nor on the tablet. I was wondering if anyone has ever come across a similar issue and has found a solution for it.

Thank you for your suggestions!